# V-Lookup Meaning

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've come to a point where another set of eyes might be best to determine the meaning of my results.

What I don't understand is that in column B my results seem to be showing up in the C (Answer) Column. However when I look at the answer column numbers inside of my Results(Column A) there seems to be fewer matches.

Column B code: = `VLOOKUP(A2,C2:C111,1,FALSE)` 
Column D code: = `VLOOKUP(C2,A2:A96,1,FALSE)`

Any thoughts of what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Without trying to really grasp what is in this sheet. You likely need to add some $ to the lookup ranges like: C$2:C$111 You probably copied the formula's down causing the range to shift along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use vlookup is wrong. [image]

I write this formula on F column:

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,$B$3:$C$10,2,FALSE)
```

This means look for the value of E3 in B column and give the value in the 2nd column. 2 means the second column of the range $B$3:$C$10 so it is column C. If I put 1 as you do, it gives the same value that you look for so it is meaningless.

Also you need to put $ as I did so the range doesn't change when you copy the formula to below.

=Vlookup(the value you look for, the range you search, the column where the value will be taken, false)

Try to understand the logic, it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your column B is the exact code that you showed? I can sense two possibilities here,
1) Either your column B is simply the element of column A
2) This is very unlikely but possible that at the very end of the column C you have all the number that belongs to A4:A43 column and also your range of the table to look for is dynamic and the range is actually changing with row